# How to open default gallery app with particular album or folder?

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, android-gallery

Every example i found on net is opening gallery and get images from gallery as result. My need is i don't want result or images to my app. I just want to trigger gallery app with showing particular folder of images. My App Have separate folder to save images. i need to navigate users directly to that path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code. It will retrieve view pictures under `storage/emulated/0/Pictures/AppPics` You can change the file path according to your directory path.

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(sdDir, "AppPics");

if (file.isDirectory()) 
    listFile = file.listFiles();
```

EDIT: To open your folder using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.fromFile(file), "/AppPics"), "image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thankyou , this is what exactly i want.. upvote my question if its reasonable.. thanks again..

Comment: It opens gallery showing "No thumbnail" in the center of blank image any suggestions ?

Comment: I have tried this solution but can't navigate into particular folder and getting toast like Unable to find Item.

Comment: This is not working on Android 11 (API level 30)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = [Uri for your folder];
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open [App] images"));
```

Comment: thankyou, i already tried it.. i don't want chooser .. problem solved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858906/7951342 this answer