# Xamarin Open gallery album

Tags: android, xamarin

Is there a way to open the default gallery app in a specific album in Xamarin? I can't find anything.

I don't need to select a photo, just open the app for view

Is there any way to open a specific folder? I have videos saved in an album and I would like to find an intent to open it without making a new page in the application

Comment: There are no default Gallery apps on an Android device.

Comment: so how can i open an album? I can only open the gallery but it tries to view an image and it doesn't show me the folder

Comment: Is there any way to open a specific folder? I have videos saved in an album and I would like to find an intent to open it without making a new page in the application

Comment: It seems that it is impossible to achieve that , On Android 10+, the file scheme is simply pointless ,check the details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59578343/8187800.